# Does the VSCode "Debugger for Chrome" extension works for extension development?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, visual-studio-code

I installed this "Debugger for Chrome" extension in VSCode, but I want to use it for developing Chrome extensions that only has a popup view.

I have this `launch.josn` in my project folder:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch popup.html",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "webRoot": "/To/My/Project-Folder"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "/To/My/Project-Folder",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "smartStep": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I first start the first configuration, and got a new Chrome window. There I can see my extension right to the address bar, so I suppose it locates my extension correctly.

Then I start the second configuration to attach, and I can see call stacks appear for both "Launch popup.html" and "Attach".

However the problem is I set a few breakpoints in `background.js` and `popup.js`, and tried to click my extension icon to launch the popup, but none of the breakpoints are hit.

Has anyone successfully used it for developing Chrome extensions?

Comment: @Young did you find any solutions?

Comment: @Young, same here, did you find a solution for that ?

Comment: @devkabiir, unfortunately didn't find a solution.

Comment: @Clement, nope, I gave up on this eventually

Answer (score 1):

I found a sort of workaround to debug chrome extension in vscode.

1. Install Debugger For Chrome and start the debugger with the following configuration.

   ```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "chrome-extension://<your-chrome-extension-id>/popup.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
   ```
2. It will create a new chrome instance however it won't open the page. then go to setting and enable developer mode and load your extension again.
3. Now refresh the `chrome-extension://<your-chrome-extension-id>/popup.html` the link and Voilà! you are connect to vscode.